# Is the space character a valid FreeBSD password?

Tags: unix, passwords, freebsd, password-management

Is the space character " " a valid FreeBSD password?

Comment: I really, really hope you're not considering using a space as your password.

Comment: As a password, or as a *part of* the password?

Comment: @Phoshi: Thanks for the concern but did I say I am going to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only when you disable the limitations in [login.conf](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login.conf&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE) you can use <kbd>SPACE</kbd> as your password with [passwd](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=passwd&sektion=1).

Comment: Which limitations?

Comment: @maxelost: `minpasswordlen`, can't remember if there was another one...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, space is a valid character for [passwords](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=passwd) in FreeBSD.